# Local State Storage in KafkaStreams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a quite simple KafkaStreams app. It looks like this:

```
input topic --> extract smth., update aggregate in the local state -> output topic
```

At the beginning the input topic had 1 partition only and everything worked smoothly.

But after I increased the number of partitions in my input topic I observe that my app is instantiated per partition, so my output topic has multiple updates (1 update per partition) instead of single update.

How can I handle this situation? I want that my app produces only one aggregate of all input partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka Streams parallelizes by partition and thus, you can only do this, by using a single partitioned topic.

If you can't control the number of topics of your input topic, you can create an intermediate topic with a single partitions and route all data through this partition.

```java
KStream multiPartitionInputStream = ...
multiPartitionInputStream.through("single-partitioned-topic")...
```

> Note: doing a global aggregation does not scale horizontally, thus, this pattern should be used with care.

**Update:**

For Processor API users, you can also provide a custom `PartitionGrouper` via config `"partition.grouper"` that creates a single task and assigns both/all partitions to this task.

> Note: providing a custom PartitionGrouper for DSL usage is highly discouraged because one needs to understand many internal details and assumptions to write a correct `PartitionGrouper`.